# realloc(): invalid pointer error when using argc and argv

Tags: c, realloc, argv, argc

As part of an exercise, I am developing a small grep-like program in C which is supposed to receive a string and some file names in order to look for that string in the referred files.

I got it working by hardcoding the name of the file and the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int searchString(char *str1, char *str2) {
    if (strstr(str1, str2) == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void searchInFile(char *filename, char *str) {
    FILE *f;
    int lineno =0;
    size_t len;
    char *buffer;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f != NULL) {
        while (getline(&buffer, &len, f) != -1) {
            lineno++;
            if (searchString(buffer, str)) {
                printf("[%s:%d] %s", filename, lineno, buffer);
            } 
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    searchInFile("loremipsum.txt", "dolor");
    return 0;
}
```

But as soon as I modify the code to chage the int main() line to add *argc* and *argv*, compile it and then run it, the script returns an error message.
The modification is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    searchInFile("loremipsum.txt", "dolor");
    return 0;
}
```

The received error:

> *** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x000056424999394d ***

Anyone knows why am I getting this error?

Comment: Yep, you never allocate memory for buffer, and so your code might do anything.

Comment: `man 3 getline`, `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` "*If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set `0` before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.*" Also, you should open and validate `f` in `main()` and then pass a `FILE*` parameter to `searchInFile` instead of `char *`.

Comment: buffer isn't set to NULL either.

Comment: I got used to easier languages such as Python and now my C is a bit rusty. As soon as I set buffer to NULL and len to 0, the code worked again. Thanks!
About opening the file in main, the exercise gives us the function prototypes so I am required to receive the filename as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Post an answer so I can mark it as solved

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes and I'm happy to oblige.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem with `getline()` was failing to initialize `len = 0;` and `buffer = NULL;` before passing `buffer` as the `lineptr` parameter and `len` as the `n` parameter. `man 3 getline`, explains:

> ```
> ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream); 
> ...
> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then 
> getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line."
> ```

Unless you initialize the pointer for `lineptr` and value for `n`, those will contain indeterminate (garbage) values that will prevent `getline` from automatically handling allocation properly.

Fixing those issues, providing a couple of minor cleanups, and enabling passing the filename and searchterm as the first and second arguments to your program, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* consider adding parameter for case-insensitive search */
int searchstring (const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    if (strstr (str1, str2) == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int searchinfile (const char *filename, char *str)
{
    int lineno = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    FILE *f = fopen (filename, "r");

    if (!f) {   /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line into buffer, search for searchstring */
    while (getline (&buffer, &len, f) != -1) {
        lineno++;
        if (searchstring (buffer, str))
            printf("[%s:%d] %s", filename, lineno, buffer);
    }
    fclose (f);     /* close file */

    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) { /* validate at least 2 arguments given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n"
                "usage: %s <file> <searchstring>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* search file argv[1] for string argv[2] */
    if (searchinfile (argv[1], argv[2]))
        fprintf (stderr, "unable to search '%s'.\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ /tmp/tmp-david/greplite dat/captnjack.txt Sea
[dat/captnjack.txt:4] On the Seven Seas.
```

Note the comment in the code -- it would be a neat trick to pass an additional parameter to indicate whether a *case-insensitive* search should be performed (and then converting both the line and search-term to lower-case before the search).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.